# How do I get distinct rows when there is a structure in a column, on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this type of table:

[image]

The last column is a struct(array) created using `STRUCT(ARRAY_AGG(...))` at some point.

Later, I need to create a table with two columns:

- The first column is an array of each distinct name

`['John', 'Tony', ...]`

- The second column is array of the structures associated with each
  player. For example:

`[struct{array[ 1 2 5 9]}  ,  struct{array [ 3 9 11] }]`

where `struct{array [ 3 9 11] }` is for `'Tony'`

The problem I am facing is I cannot do:

```
select distinct name, favoritePlayerHours from ...
```

because the `favoritePlayHours` is a structure. If I do not want to select `owned_game` how do I select the unique rows?

Answer (score 0):

You have to UNNEST it first to be able to distinct the favouritePlayerHours and re-aggregate it.

```
SELECT 
name, 
FORMAT('%T', ARRAY_AGG(favoritePlayerHours) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) favoritePlayerHours
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT name, 
        favoritePlayerHours 
    FROM 
        table 
    UNNEST(favoritePlayerHours) favoritePlayerHours
)
```

You can learn more about the array operation on BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays).

Comment: Could you please confirm if this is correct? The "favoritePlayerHours" is not an array. It is a structure which has an array. I wrapped the array inside a structure because later I wanted to do array of arrays.

Comment: I assumed that you can get different numbers inside the array of hours e.g [1,2,4] and [1,2,3] for a player. In addition, I also assumed that favoritePlayerHours already access your struct element of interest e.g. struct.elm1.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I ended up doing:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
 (  
    SELECT
       name, 
       favoritePlayerHours,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name) rownum
    FROM table
 )
where rownum = 1
```

However, this only works because I do know how the column is prepared and is probably not the general solution.